# Regex within html tags

Tags: python, html, regex, html-parsing

I would like to parse the HD price from the following snipper of HTML. I am only have fragments of the html code, so I cannot use an HTML parser for this.

```
<div id="left-stack">        
  <span>View In iTunes</span></a>
 <span class="price">£19.99</span>
 <ul class="list">
    <li>HD Version</li>
```

Basically, the format would be to "Find the price before the word "HD Version" (case insensitive). Here is what I have so far:

```
re.match(r'^(\d|.){1,6}...HD\sVersion', string)
```

How would I extract the value "19.99" from the above string?

Comment: Please insert here the usual admonishment about parsing HTML with regex

Comment: I cannot do that, I don't have the full html. I only have the above snippet as a string.

Comment: you can still use BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is [very lenient](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) to the HTML it parses, you can use it for the chunks/parts of HTML too:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = u"""
<div id="left-stack">
  <span>View In iTunes</span></a>
 <span class="price">£19.99</span>
 <ul class="list">
    <li>HD Version</li>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print soup.find('span', class_='price').text[1:]
```

Prints:

```
19.99
```

Answer (score 4):

You've asked for a regular expression here, but it's not the right tool for parsing HTML. Use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for this.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = '''
<div id="left-stack">        
  <span>View In iTunes</span></a>
 <span class="price">£19.99</span>
 <ul class="list">
    <li>HD Version</li>'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> val  = soup.find('span', {'class':'price'}).text
>>> print val[1:]
19.99
```

Answer (score 2):

You can still parse using `BeautifulSoup`, you don't need the full html:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="""
<div id="left-stack">
  <span>View In iTunes</span></a>
 <span class="price">£19.99</span>
 <ul class="list">
    <li>HD Version</li>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
sp = soup.find(attrs={"class":"price"}) 
print sp.text[1:]
19.99
```

Answer (score 2):

The current BeautifulSoup answers only show how to grab all `<span class="price">` tags. This is better:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = """<div id="left-stack">        
 <span>View In iTunes</span></a>
 <span class="price">£19.99</span>
 <ul class="list">
    <li>HD Version</li>"""

for HD_Version in (tag for tag in soup('li') if tag.text.lower() == 'hd version'):
    price = HD_Version.parent.findPreviousSibling('span', attrs={'class':'price'}).text
```

In general, using regular expressions to parse an irregular language like HTML is asking for trouble. Stick with an established parser.

Comment: If the OP only has the snippet then there is only one `span class="price">`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Right, but I don't necessarily trust the OP's input. This should grab the first `<span class="price">` before the `<ul>` that contains `<li>HD Version</li>`. After all if OP only has that exact snippet, then why is he looking for a programmatic solution?

Comment: @Unihedron fair enough. I added a clarification that I was referring to the beautifulsoup answers, and also the usual warning not to do what OP is trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\D+HD Version)
```

- `\D+` skips ahead of non-digits in a lookahead, effectively asserting that our match (`19.99`) is the last digit ahead of `HD Version`.

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/eU2sJ8/1).

Use the `i` modifier in the regex to make the matching case-insensitive and change `+` to`*` if the number can be directly before `HD Version`.